# Language filter in SonarQube component_tree url

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

The api `api/measures/component_tree` gives the list of components based on the provided input filters. Is there any parameter to provide the language so that the returned list only contains components of that language?

Answer (score 0):

No, currently you cannot filter on language.

You could do it like this:

1. Find all potentially relevant components with [`api/measures/component_tree`](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/measures/component_tree)
2. Use [`api/components/show`](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/components/show) to get the language of each of those
3. Only take components, that are included in 1. and have your desired language in 2.

Comment: But the above mentioned URL doesn't have metricKeys parameter. My need is to search based on metric keys.

Comment: @slardan I don't think that work around will satisfy the use case. Because both are two different APIs. First API wont return the entire set of files. It will return only the number of values based on page size and metric key. Second API will return different set of values since it don't have metric keys. So merging both the APIs won't work in this case.